# Auto scroll div does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I probably want to make a div auto scroll to the bottom of the page when content is loaded but it actually doesnt scroll heres my code on jquery:

```
function auto_scrollmes(){
    //undefined ang scrollheight.
    var div = $(".convo_mes").scrollHeight;
    alert(div);
    div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;
}
```

When i tried to alert div it alerts undefined.Here is what's in my css:

```
#convo_mes{
text-align:left;
width:98%;
height:80%;
}

.convo_mes{
text-align:left;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:#fff;
border:1px solid #000;
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:auto;
 }
```

Actually when i click on a message the content of the message will be loaded on the div with class of convo_mes:

```
$(".mes").click(function(){
    var user = $(this).attr("id");      
    $("#convo").html("<b>"+user+"</b>");
    $("#convo_ctrl").show();
    $(".send_to").attr("id",user);
    $(".convo_mes").html("Loading conversation <img width='15' height='15' src='./img/load.gif'>");

    $.post("./php/view_msg.php",{friend:user},function(view_msg){
        $("#"+user).html(user+" "+view_msg);
    });

    setTimeout(function(){get_convo()},2000);
    setTimeout(function(){auto_scrollmes()},3000);

});
```

I tried everything and heres my HTML code:

```
<div id="convo_mes">
<div class="convo_mes">

</div>
</div>
```

I checked the console and it shows the "global.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of undefined" error, the 24th line in the global.js is div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(".convo_mes")` is a jQuery object and not a DOM object.
Access the DOM object like this: `$(".convo_mes")[0]`

This should work.

```
function auto_scrollmes(){
    //undefined ang scrollheight.
    var div = $(".convo_mes")[0];
    alert(div);
    div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;
}
```

Comment: Now i cant see the error in the console log but still it doesnt auto scroll to the bottom. By the way what are the difference between DOM and Jquery object.

Comment: DOM is the browser's representation of Document Object Model. jQuery is a custom framework that wraps the DOM so that you can run custom built functionality on them that also helps with cross-browser compliance, because not all browsers implement DOM the same.

Comment: I can't see any other problems with your code and without a JSFiddle there's nothing I can do.

Comment: It alerts 1024 but it does not scroll to the bottom. :(

Comment: Now i know whats the problem, hahaha. You messed up with the code.
You wrote div.scrollTop, actually div is a variable of scrollHeight so now ur using it as a variable of a div, so it turned out that u wrote $(".convo_mes")[0].scrollHeight.scrollTop = $(".convo_mes")[0].scrollHeight.scrollHeight thats why it didnt work. HAHAHAHA! no worked after i edited the codes.